# Websocket using actors vs Websocket iteratees in Play Scala

Tags: scala, websocket, playframework-2.0, actor, loops

The following [link](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWebSockets) explains how to use WebSocket in Play using both **Actors** and **Iteratees** but they haven't explained the difference between.

What are the difference in two approaches?